# Deployed Ios Application always force close

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

i have developed an application for Ipad.
at first, when i deploy my application to Ipad, there're no problem on application.
But after 2 weeks(im not sure it's 1 or 2 weeks), application suddenly 
start to force close when i open on my Ipad.
I developed it using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.
any suggestion to solve this problem?
(sorry for my bad grammar)

Comment: Do you have a paid or free developer program membership?

Comment: @Paulw11 No, i don't

Comment: That is an either/or question. Either you have a paid or a free membership. I will assume that you have a free membership. In this case you will need to reinstall your app using xcode. Free provisioning profiles have a limited validity.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you paul, i'm sorry for asking a silly question, i ask this because i don't find any answer for my question.